# How do I combine two booleans columns into one varchar columns in a SELECT query?

Tags: mysql

So I have a table containing two boolean columns called "master" and "edition". I did not make this table, somebody else made it, the table is already filled with a lot of data and I cannot change it so this is what I have to work with.

Now this is needed:
I need to do a SELECT statement, where I combine the master and edition columns into a new column. The new column should contain either the letter 'm' (when master is 1), 'e' (when edition is 1) or 'u' (when both are 0). Now I have no clue how to do that. Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: What value should is have is `master` and `edition` are both 1, or can this never happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
CASE
    WHEN master = 0 and edition = 0 THEN 'u'
    WHEN master = 1 and edition = 0 THEN 'm'
    WHEN master = 0 and edition = 1 THEN 'e'
    ELSE '???' -- when either are one???
END 
from myTable
```

Comment: Thank you! I eventually used

    CASE
    WHEN master = 0 and edition = 0 THEN 'u'
    WHEN master = 1 and edition = 0 THEN 'm'
    WHEN master = 0 and edition = 1 THEN 'e'
    END AS `ume`

They are never both 1

Comment: Hi, ok, but if a combination 1 and 1 go out, you've NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. Using `CASE` is the simplest, there is another one:
if there are no rows with `master=1` and `edition=1`, this will work:

```
select *, 'm' from table where master=1
union
select *, 'e' from table where edition=1
union
select *, 'u' from table where edition=0 and master=0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update the value of a new column, you could use this query:

```
UPDATE
  tablename
SET
  new = CASE WHEN NOT (master OR edition) THEN 'u'
             ELSE
               CONCAT_WS('',
                 CASE WHEN master THEN 'm' END,
                 CASE WHEN edition THEN 'e' END)
        END
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55fa96/1).

This will return `u` if both values are false, `m` if master is true, `e` if edition is true, `me` if they are both true.

Comment: I might use this eventually in the future so thank you. I wish I could upvote you, but I can't.